# Material UI DateRangePicker how to pick year to year only

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

how can I customize DateRangePicker to only pick Start Year to End Year only? Is it possible?

```
<LocalizationProvider
      dateAdapter={AdapterDateFns}
      localeText={{ start: "Check-in", end: "Check-out" }}
    >
      <DateRangePicker
        value={value}
        onChange={(newValue) => {
          setValue(newValue);
        }}
        renderInput={(startProps, endProps) => (
          <React.Fragment>
            <TextField {...startProps} />
            <Box sx={{ mx: 2 }}> to </Box>
            <TextField {...endProps} />
          </React.Fragment>
        )}
      />
    </LocalizationProvider>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import * as React from 'react';
import TextField from '@mui/material/TextField';
import { AdapterDateFns } from '@mui/x-date-pickers/AdapterDateFns';
import { LocalizationProvider } from '@mui/x-date-pickers/LocalizationProvider';
import { DatePicker } from '@mui/x-date-pickers/DatePicker';
import Stack from '@mui/material/Stack';

export default function ViewsDatePicker() {
  const [value, setValue] = React.useState(new Date());

  return (
    <LocalizationProvider dateAdapter={AdapterDateFns}>
      <Stack spacing={3}>
        <DatePicker
          views={['year']}
          label="Year only"
          value={value}
          onChange={(newValue) => {
            setValue(newValue);
          }}
          renderInput={(params) => <TextField {...params} helperText={null} />}
        />        
      </Stack>
    </LocalizationProvider>
  );
}
```

Comment: It's not DateRangePicker, its just a single field, I've tried that and I was just wondering if DateRangePicker can only pick year